# Convert int64 column to datetime column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one column 'time', which is the object `int64` and looks like this:

```
time
202003180001043
202003180001044
```

And which should be converted to a datetime column:

```
time
2020-03-18 00:01:043
2020-03-18 00:01:044
```

When I run the command:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y%m%d%I%M%S')
```

I get the error: *ValueError: unconverted data remains: 04*

How canI include the last numbers?

Comment: Seconds can't have triple digits. Looks like you have to take in account fractions of seconds in your formatting string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is `%I` is for hour in 12hours format, so failed. Need `%H` for hours in 24hours format:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
print (df)
                     time
0 2020-03-18 00:01:04.300
1 2020-03-18 00:01:04.400
```

Comment: when I do this i get: 2020-03-01 08:00:01.043 , but It should be: 2020-03-18

Comment: @PV8 - is possible multiple by `10` ?